# Can Handler.php determine if the current route has auth middleware applied?

Tags: laravel, exception

I want to branch the process in Handler.php depending on whether the page requires authentication or not.

Below is an example.
Is this possible?

I use Auth which is the basic function of Laravel.
Authentication is controlled by writing `middleware(['auth:web'])` in `web.php`.

#### Handler.php

```php
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
      if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        if( {{ required authentication root }}) {

        } else if( {{ not required authentication root }})
      
        }
      }

      return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of applied middleware using

```
request()->route()->action['middleware']
```

OR as per @lagbox's suggestion (which is much cleaner, thank you @lagbox)

```
request()->route()->middleware()
```

Comment: nice, also `...route()->middleware()` :)